# Skip pytest test cases if marked as quarantined

Tags: python, pytest

I have a few test cases which would always fail. I'm using pytest-quarantine module to mark those test case as xfail using a quarantine.txt.

- If the marked test fails, it marks XFAIL
- If the marked test passes, it results into XPASS

However, with this approach, the test cases are still being executed taking a lot of time in the whole test suit.

Is there a way, I can skip the test cases mentioned in quarantine.txt?

Note: I have a single test case which is being executed with around 1500 parameters to test each scenario. So marking the failing test with `@skip` is not an option for me.  Currently, test with around 150 parameters is failing. I am using a fixture to parametrize the single test case.

pytest-quarantine link: https://pypi.org/project/pytest-quarantine/

Comment: You could use the quarantine plugin code as a template for a similar plugin that skips the tests (it is quite straightforward). Or better yet, add an option for skipping to the plugin and submit a PR to the project :)

Comment: That's a very good idea. I was just looking for an existing project, so I don't have to reinvent the wheel. But if it doesn't exist, I would be happy to raise a PR soon.!

Comment: I'm the maintainer of pytest-quarantine, and adding an option for applying `skip` instead of `xfail` sounds like a good idea. I'm also wondering if there's a workaround for your particular use case. Either way, feel free to [open an issue](https://github.com/EnergySage/pytest-quarantine/issues) for discussion, before submitting a PR.

Comment: You can choose to have the quarantined tests not collected. `pytest -m "not quarantined"` should do.

Comment: `pytest.mark.xfail()` has a `run` parameter that can be set to `False` (see [reference](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html#pytest-mark-xfail)). If you want to implement it, have a look at [the line that adds the marker](https://github.com/EnergySage/pytest-quarantine/blob/bc2c42869be4ea72f3ac297ac29675e0cd86786c/src/pytest_quarantine/plugin.py#L144).